# bootstrap 3 grid with fixed width content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use a bootstrap 3 grid to set up some responsive behavior:

I want to have two columns and have the one on the right be visible only from some minimum width.

But this column is supposed to have an image inside it.

The issue is that the image has some width (339px) and I would not like the column including it to be visible if its width can only smaller than this.

Is there a way to tell a grid column to become hidden when it drops below a specific width?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses CSS media queries to determine responsive behavior. Media queries can be used to detect width of the viewport, but not the width of a specific element like your column. So, I think you'd have to use something like jQuery or JavaScript to handle the window resize event and test the width of your column..

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
   var ele = $('#myCol');
   if (ele.outerWidth()<339) {
        ele.hide();
   }
   else {
        ele.show();
   }
 });
```

http://www.bootply.com/120897